# can not create or edit attribute set

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, attribute-set

When I want to create a new attribute set, magento can not complete the process and the browser error "`This page isn’t working`" and if I want edit a attribute set that I created before magento error unable to edit it.

How can I fix it?

Comment: did you look at the logs?

Comment: which logs? I checked nginx error logs but nothing be there.